Spacing between equations in columns in Beamer
I am currently creating a Beamer presentation and I am somewhat new to LaTeX. I have two columns with three equations in each, and I want the columns to have less vertical space between them. I have tried \vspace, \minipage, etc. and nothing is working. I only want to change the vertical space on this frame.
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Relationships in Permutation $w$}

        \vspace{.5cm}

        \begin{center}

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
             \textit{w(1)} & \textit{w(2)} & \textit{w(3)} & \textit{w(4)} \\
             \hline
             3 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
             \hline
        \end{tabular}
            
        \end{center}

    \begin{columns}

        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

       \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(1) < w(2) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 2? \; \textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}


        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Red}{ w(1) < w(3) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 4? \;\textcolor{Red} {\tikzxmark}}
        \end{equation*}

        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(1) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 1? \;\textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}
        
        \end{column}

        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}

         \begin{equation*}
             \colorboxed{Red}{w(2) < w(3) \Longleftrightarrow 2 > 4? \;\textcolor{Red} {\tikzxmark}}
        \end{equation*}

        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(2) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 2 > 1? \;\textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}

        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(3) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 4 > 1? \;\textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}

        \end{column}

    \end{columns}

    \vspace{1cm}

    This means we have the inversion set

    $$Inv(w)=\bigl\{(3,2),(3,1),(2,1),(4,1)\bigl\}.$$
    
\end{frame}


Any ideas?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your document example compilable. Where is \colorboxed defined?

You can avoid much of vertical space by removing the empty lines in your source code:
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzxmark}{%
\tikz[scale=0.23] {
    \draw[line width=0.7,line cap=round] (0,0) to [bend left=6] (1,1);
    \draw[line width=0.7,line cap=round] (0.2,0.95) to [bend right=3] (0.8,0.05);
}}
\newcommand{\tikzcmark}{%
\tikz[scale=0.23] {
    \draw[line width=0.7,line cap=round] (0.25,0) to [bend left=10] (1,1);
    \draw[line width=0.8,line cap=round] (0,0.35) to [bend right=1] (0.23,0);
}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\colorboxed}[3][white]{\fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#3$}}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Relationships in Permutation $w$}

        \vspace{.5cm}

        \begin{center}

        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
             \textit{w(1)} & \textit{w(2)} & \textit{w(3)} & \textit{w(4)} \\
             \hline
             3 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
             \hline
        \end{tabular}
            
        \end{center}

    \begin{columns}
       \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
       \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(1) < w(2) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 2? \; \textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}
        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Red}{ w(1) < w(3) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 4? \;\textcolor{Red} {\tikzxmark}}
        \end{equation*}
        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(1) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 1? \;\textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
         \begin{equation*}
             \colorboxed{Red}{w(2) < w(3) \Longleftrightarrow 2 > 4? \;\textcolor{Red} {\tikzxmark}}
        \end{equation*}
        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(2) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 2 > 1? \;\textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}
        \begin{equation*}
            \colorboxed{Green}{w(3) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 4 > 1? \;\textcolor{Green} {\tikzcmark}}
        \end{equation*}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

    \vspace{1cm}

    This means we have the inversion set

    $$Inv(w)=\bigl\{(3,2),(3,1),(2,1),(4,1)\bigl\}.$$
    
\end{frame}


\end{document}



With exploiting amsmath package, which loaded by beamer document class and using pifont package for check marks and X cross marks you can write your slide with quite shorter code:
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand\tCM{\textcolor{teal}{\text{\ding{51}}}}% you can defined own, to you more meaning names
\newcommand\rXSB{\textcolor{red}{\text{\ding{55}}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\colorboxed}[3][white]{\fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#3$}}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Relationships in Permutation $w$}

\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
w(1)    & w(2)  & w(3)  & w(4)  \\
    \hline
3       & 2     & 4     & 1     \\
     \hline
\end{array}
\]

  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{gather*}
\colorboxed{Green}{w(1) < w(2) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 2? \; \tCM}  \\[1ex]
\colorboxed{Green}{w(1) < w(3) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 4? \; \rXSB} \\[1ex]
\colorboxed{Green}{w(1) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 3 > 2? \; \tCM}
\end{gather*}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{gather*}
\colorboxed{Red}{w(2) < w(3) \Longleftrightarrow 2 > 4? \;\rXSB}    \\[1ex]
\colorboxed{Green}{w(2) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 2 > 1? \;\tCM}   \\[1ex]
\colorboxed{Green}{w(3) < w(4) \Longleftrightarrow 4 > 1? \;\tCM}
\end{gather*}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\vspace{1cm}
This means we have the inversion set
\[
\text{Inv}(w)=\bigl\{(3,2),(3,1),(2,1),(4,1)\bigl\}.
\]
 
\end{frame}
\end{document}


BTW: as you can see in above MWE is considered that

numbers and operators are usual written by upright shapes
variables are in italic shapes
in LaTeX documents instead of $$ should be use \[ \] or begin{equation*} and \end{equation*}

